# Google Chrome version 80 on GalliumOS reliably crashes after several hours

Tags: google-chrome, chromebox

I have about 50 Chromeboxes running GalliumOS, displaying the same HTTP pages all day (dashboards) using Chrome version 80.0.3987.116.

For the past couple weeks, Chrome has been crashing every 18 hours or so, on every single Chromebox. It becomes unresponsive and I have to kill the process or restart the box.

I'm testing Chrome on one of them using this command that loads a given URL:

```
google-chrome-stable --load-media-router-component-extension=0 --disable-session-crashed-bubble --enable-logging --v=1 app="http://192.168.x.x/whatever"
```

(The --load-media-router-component-extension=0 is a workaround we put in for a previous issue- the Chrome Media Router was reliably crashing after only a few hours, and we aren't using Chromecast anyway, so that was a no-brainer. And --disable-session-crashed-bubble is to get rid of a modal dialog; we only have SSH access to these things.)

I came in this morning and it was locked up on schedule. On STDOUT it kept printing this over and over again:

```
[12171:1:0100/00000.627388:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(46)] Received unexpected number of handles
[12171:1:0100/00000.627421:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(94)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: AllocateAndMapSharedMemory failed
```

In chrome_debug.log I'm finding this at the end (repeated over and over):

```
[12171:1:0100/000000.404872:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(94)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: AllocateAndMapSharedMemory failed
[12171:1:0100/000000.405038:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(46)] Received unexpected number of handles
```

Right now, to get around this we're running a cron job that restarts lightdm on each Chromebox after a couple hours, but we're considering downgrading all of them to whatever the last stable version of Chrome was, 79 or 78.

Comment: FWIW it appears that this is caused by a memory leak; any page just being open causes a 20% increase in RAM over several hours until the process locks up.